# How to build a downstream job with postbuild groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, build, pipeline

I am trying to build a downstream job using groovy script in jenkins.
I have installed the **Groovy Postbuild plugin** it gives me the below options in a freestyle job's postbuild section.
[image: stack]
Please note *TestDownstream* is the job name which I want to start/trigger/invoke as the post build action.

I have tried

```
build 'TestDownstream'
```

```
node{
   build 'TestDownstream'
}
```

```
node{
   stage('TestDownstream')
}
```

and a few more variants like this.

I am getting this error as:

```
Groovy script failed:

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.build() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [TestDownstream]
Possible solutions: find(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), run(), run(), dump()
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:585)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:623)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:594)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript.evaluate(SecureGroovyScript.java:377)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript.evaluate(SecureGroovyScript.java:314)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.GroovyPostbuildRecorder.perform(GroovyPostbuildRecorder.java:406)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:803)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:752)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:177)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:697)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1932)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help.

build job: 'job path', wait: 'false', parameters:
[
string (name: 'xx', value: "$xx"),
string (name: 'yy', value: "$yy")
]

Comment: what is a jo path? and why parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [schedule method](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Queue.html) to trigger a job from post build

```
import jenkins.*

Jenkins.instance.queue.schedule(
      Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('NAME_OF_JOB'),
      0,  // quietPeriod
      new ParametersAction(
        [
          new StringParameterValue('PARAM_NAME', PARAM_VALUE),
        ]
      )
   )
```